# Codeigniter DB Query chaining wrong data from previous calls

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

This is what I have in my model. I inherited somebody else's code and trying to clean it up (can't change column names yet)

```
$ad_where = array('id'=>$id, 'client'=>$this->brand->client['id']);
$this->db->select('id, client, user, code, heading, subhead, `from`, `to`, openings, view_only, publish, closed')->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get_where('adverts', $ad_where);

if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
    $row = $query->row_array();

    if( $row['heading'] == 'n/a' ){
        $row['heading'] = $this->job_title_heading($row['id'], $row['client']);
    }

    return $row;
    }

    return FALSE;
```

CodeIgniter returns an error with the following output:

Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'adverts'

```
SELECT `id`, `client`, `user`, `code`, `heading`, `subhead`, `from`, `to`, `openings`, `view_only`, `publish`, `closed` FROM (`adverts`, `adverts`, `adverts`, `adverts`, `adverts`, `adverts`, `adverts`, `adverts`, `adverts`, `adverts`) INNER JOIN `advert_location_links` ON `advert_location_links`.`advert`=`adverts`.`id` INNER JOIN `advert_location_links` ON `advert_location_links`.`advert`=`adverts`.`id` INNER JOIN `advert_location_links` ON `advert_location_links`.`advert`=`adverts`.`id` INNER JOIN `advert_location_links` ON `advert_location_links`.`advert`=`adverts`.`id` INNER JOIN `advert_location_links` ON `advert_location_links`.`advert`=`adverts`.`id` INNER JOIN `advert_location_links` ON `advert_location_links`.`advert`=`adverts`.`id` INNER JOIN `advert_location_links` ON `advert_location_links`.`advert`=`adverts`.`id` INNER JOIN `advert_location_links` ON `advert_location_links`.`advert`=`adverts`.`id` INNER JOIN `advert_location_links` ON `advert_location_links`.`advert`=`adverts`.`id` WHERE (truncated) LIMIT 1
```

The added JOIN is from a previous statement.

I have tried adding

```
$this->db->stop_cache();
$this->db->flush_cache();
```

But that doesn't help

EDIT: The previous call was not resetting the statement because it was poorly formed and although it seemed to execute, it was not done properly. It was a count_all/count_all_results() call which I changed to a SELECT statements and used num_rows() to get total results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you end the previous query with getting some results? Because if you left it hanging it will be chained with the next statements.

Try calling once **$this->db->result();** before starting this query to test that there is nothing waiting.

And if i can give a rewrite your code it will be like so:

```
$row = $this->db
    ->select('id, client, user, code, heading, subhead, from, to, openings, view_only, publish, closed')
    ->get_where('adverts', array('id'=>$id, 'client'=>$this->brand->client['id']))
    ->limit(1)
    ->row();

if(!$row)
  return false;

if($row['heading'] == 'n/a' )
    $row['heading'] = $this->job_title_heading($row['id'], $row['client']);

return $row;
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I appreciate your comment. It helped me get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend putting the query directly after you escape the strings. CodeIgniter's query builder has a lot of issues and can't work properly when there are several calls.

Comment: I learned his the hard way. Thanks for your contribution. I changed the previous query after the comments and it cleared everything. Thanks